# Why do none of the instance methods work on DateTime object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
require 'date'
now = DateTime.now
sunday = now - now.wday

>> sunday = now - now.wday
=> #<DateTime: 53058180361250947/21600000000,-5/24,2299161>
```

Since `sunday` is a `DateTime` object, I should be able to call its instance methods such as `to_date` or `midnight`, both of which are listed in the Rails documentation.

However, this is what I get

```
>> sunday.to_time
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_time' for #<DateTime: 53058180361250947/21600000000,-5/24,2299161>
        from (irb):17
```

Actually none of these instance methods work on it. I'm using irb mode, and I do not know what's going on. Can any one tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not Ruby methods, they're Rails methods, specifically in Active Support. And, in IRB, Active Support is not loaded by default.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_time

Comment: how to load ActiveSupport?

Comment: `require 'activesupport/all'` to load everything

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to:

```
require 'active_support/time'
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't `require` the Active Support module. You can load the entire module using `require 'activesupport/all'` however that is overkill most of the time.

Instead, Active Support allows us to cherry-pick functionality we want to include with our code. "[Active Support Core Extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)" will tell you all about it. You probably want to look at these sections:

- "[Extensions to Date](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date)"
- "[Extensions to DateTime](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-datetime)"
- "[Extensions to Time](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-time)"